# Showing that $f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: (0, \frac\pi2) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x}.$
>
> Show that $f$ is strictly decreasing.

This was handed out by our professor and this was he's approach.

By definition $f$ is strictly decreasing if there exists an $x$ and $y$ s.t.

$$0 < x < y < \frac\pi2 \Longrightarrow f(x) > f(y).$$

Also by definition if $f$ is differentiable function whose derivative $f'$ is strictly decreasing on some open interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R},$ then $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(a, b).$

So using this we can compute the derivative $f'$

$$f'(x) = \frac{x\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{x^2}.$$

Notice that when $x \in(0, \frac\pi2)$ we have

$$f'(x) <0 \Longleftrightarrow x\cos(x) -\sin(x) <0.$$

Now we can define a new function $h:[0, \frac\pi2) \to \mathbb{R},$

$$h(x) = x\cos(x)-\sin(x).$$

Also $h$ is differentiable on $(0, \frac\pi2)$ and

$$h'(x) =-x\sin(x) <0, \text{when } x \in(0, \frac\pi2).$$

Now let $x \in (0, \frac\pi2)$ be arbitary. Using the Mean Value Theorem we can find an $\xi \in(0, x)$ s.t

$$h'(\xi) = \frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x-0}$$

from where we get

$$h(x) =h(0)+h'(\xi)x =0+h'(\xi)x <0.$$

And therefore $f'(x) < 0$ so the original function $f$ is strictly decreasing.

So my question is that can we use some alternative approach here since the Mean Value Theorem and the part "Now let $x \in (0, \frac\pi2)$ be arbitary. Using the Mean Value Theorem we can find an $\xi \in(0, x)$ " is kinda weird to me, especially I don't understand why do we investigate something like $(0, x)$ instead of $(0, \frac\pi2)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small trick that makes the answer trivial: $\frac {\sin x } x=\int_0^{1} \cos (tx) dt$ and $\cos (tx)$ is decreasing on $(0,\pi/2)$ for $0 <t<1$.

Answer (score 1):

You already have

$$h(x) = x\cos(x)-\sin(x) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note $h(0) = 0$. Since you also have

$$h'(x) =-x\sin(x) <0, \text{when } x \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

this means $h(x) \lt 0 \; \; \forall \; \; x \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Going back to what you had earlier, this means $f'(x) = \frac{x\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{x^2} \lt 0$ in that same interval and, thus, $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing.